# Oracle SQL : Need float column with default one decimal value in select query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table DATA_TABLE, it have  MAX_RATE_UNIT column as float value.

Below is the table and MAX_RATE_UNIT column values like,

```
DATA_TABLE
----------
MAX_RATE_UNIT
-----------
1.2
1
3
3.4
0.445
2343.43434
2.123
0.3433423
```

I want a select query which has return the result as minimum one decimal point if the decimal is not have in tha column value, as 1--> 1.0 and 3-> 3.0 and remaing are same value to return,

OUTPUT:

```
MAX_RATE_UNIT
-------------
1.2
**1.0**
**3.0**
3.4
0.445
2343.43434
2.123
0.3433423
```

Help me for this logic,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the number to a string explicitly with `to_char()` and a suitable format model:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with data_table (max_rate_unit) as (
            select 1.2 from dual
  union all select 1 from dual
  union all select 3 from dual
  union all select 3.4 from dual
  union all select 0.445 from dual
  union all select 2343.43434 from dual
  union all select 2.123 from dual
  union all select 0.3433423 from dual
)
-- actual query
select to_char(max_rate_unit, 'FM999999990.099999999') as max_rate_unit
from data_table;

MAX_RATE_UNIT       
--------------------
1.2
1.0
3.0
3.4
0.445
2343.43434
2.123
0.3433423
```

Strategically using `0` instead of `9` immediately before and after the decimal point means you get a leading zero for values < 1, and at least one digit after the decimal point; the `FM` modifier stops that showing all the trailing digits.

You  need enough placeholders in toe format model, either side of the decimal point, to account for the full range of values you might have to handle. (My original edit didn't have enough so the last digit of the last value was silently truncated...)